# jquery: get value from clicked div

Tags: jquery

```
<div>'.$i.'</div>
```

$i is auto generated by loop - which could lead to:

```
<div>'.$i.'</div>
<div>'.$i.'</div>
<div>'.$i.'</div>
```

etc. where each $i is different.

How do I get value of particular $i (using jQuery), when div is clicked.

In standard JS I would use onClick($i).
In jQuery I just do not know, how to pick that val.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you don't have any other way to identify the `<div>` elements, this would place a handler on *every* `<div>` on the page.

```
$('div').click(function() {
    var text = $(this).text();
    // do something with the text
});
```

The [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) method will return the text content for that `<div>`, (as well as any nested elements).

If you only wanted the `click` event on certain `<div>` elements, the best is to add a class, and select the correct ones based on that.

```
$('div.myClass').click(function() {
    var text = $(this).text();
    // do something with the text
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="myClass">'.$i.'</div>
<div class="myClass">'.$i.'</div>
<div class="myClass">'.$i.'</div>

<div>some other div</div>
```

If the `<div>` elements are all within the same ancestor element, you could use [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) instead, which will place one handler on the ancestor to handle all divs inside.

```
$('#parentID').delegate('div.myClass', 'click', function() {
    var text = $(this).text();
    // do something with the text
});
```

HTML

```
<div id="parentID">
    <div class="myClass">'.$i.'</div>
    <div class="myClass">'.$i.'</div>
    <div class="myClass">'.$i.'</div>
</div>
```

*(Requires jQuery 1.4 or later)*

Comment: @karim79 - When I get to a question and I see *"viewed 0 times"*, I know I have a fighting chance. :o)

Comment: @ patrick dw:
Thank you very much for taking time to explain it to me,
now it seems so simple.
Before posting I was googlin' quite a bit, but I was not able to ask se the right question.
thank you again
Jeff

Answer (score 5):

```
$('div').click(function(event){
  alert($(this).text());
});
```

A more efficient solution (since it seems you have a lot of `<div>`s would be to add a live event to the wrapping element of those, like this:

```
$('#container').live('click', function(event){
   if(event.target.tagName == "DIV") alert($(event.target).text());
});
```

Comment: For your second code example, to get the text for the correct `<div>` you'll want to do `$(event.target).text()` instead. `this` refers to the `#container` element. ...or do `#container div` in the selector to use `this`.

Comment: Pablo,
Thank you for the time you took writing your explanation.
Jeff

Comment: Cool man, no problem. I really did not explain thoroughly how live events work (and the **do** come in handy believe me), you can read about those here -> http://api.jquery.com/live/